# C wait for time or signal with sigwait

Tags: c, signals, sleep

I want to wait X secondes or when signal arrived.

I can use `sigwait` but that only listen for signal , without timeout.

What is the right way do to that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sigtimedwait()` function, which returns after a timeout given as a parameter. 
Here is the documentation : http://www2.phys.canterbury.ac.nz/dept/docs/manuals/unix/DEC_4.0e_Docs/HTML/MAN/MAN3/1795____.HTM

By reading the documentation, you can see that the return value of this function identifies what is the cause :

```
ERRORS

  If the sigwait functions fail, errno is set to one of the following values:

  [EINVAL]   The value of the set parameter contains an invalid or
         unsupported signal number.

  [EINVAL]   The timeout argument specified a tv_nsec value that is less
         than 0 or greater than or equal to 1,000,000,000.

  [EINTR]    The wait was interrupted by an unblocked, caught signal.

  [EAGAIN]   No signal specified by set was delivered within the
         specified timeout period.
```

You may want to check if the value is `EAGAIN` or `EINTR`

Comment: How can I know if `sigtimedwait` finish because timeout or because signal arrived ?

Comment: errno will be EAGAIN  and `sigtimedwait` will return -1 ?

Comment: You have to check the value of errno after the terminaison of the function.