# Using a signal listener thread - how do I stop it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, signals

A snippet from my main method:

```
  std::atomic_bool runflag;
  // ...
  std::thread signaller([&]() mutable {
    while (runflag) {
      int sig;
      int rcode = sigwait(&set, &sig);
      if (rcode == 0) {
        switch (sig) {
          case SIGINT: {
            // handle ^C
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
  while (runflag) {
    next = cin.get();
    // handle character input
  }
  signaller.join();
```

I'm using the `sigwait()`-based approach for detecting `SIGINT` sent from the command line.

The `signaller` thread uses `sigwait()` to listen for signals. The program terminates when `runflag` is set false. However, the `signaller` thread will still be blocked at `sigwait` when this happens. I don't think I can use condition variables, as sigwait has no way to hook into one. Is there an alternative solution that is preferably not Linux-only?

EDIT 1: Alternatively, is there an interruptible version of sigwait?

Comment: `sigwait` is Linux only. So if you want a non-Linux-only solution you ought to ditch it in the first place and use condition variable instead.

Comment: @ALX23z Other Unix-like OSes have `sigwait()` too (e.g. [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sigwait.2.html) and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sigwait&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE)).

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974829/waiting-thread-until-a-condition-has-been-occurred

Comment: You can use `sigtimedwait()` to check `runflag` even when signal will not arrived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sigtimedwait()` function, which returns after a timeout given as a parameter.

You will need to check the return value from `sigtimedwait()` to check if it finished because of timeout or the signal arrived and then depending on this value you will need to handle signal or just check `runflag` and run again `sigtimedwait()`.

Here is more about it from another answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58834251/11424134

Comment: Polling is usually not a good idea. If you make the polling interval small, you waste CPU time. If you make it large, you make your  program exit slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can wake up the signal-handling thread by having the process send another signal to itself, eg.

```
kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
```